# Deselect markers - google maps

Tags: google-maps

I have a google maps, with multiple markers, when I click on a marker the image of a marker changes.
Now I want when I click on another marker, the previous one I want to returns to the original image.
How can I do that?

Comment: Please specify more details with code, which platform and language are you using.

Comment: And search for duplicates.